# OpenBSD boost compiler error

Tags: boost, bjam

I am trying to build boost 1.53 from the ports branch and I get the following errors

```
error: Duplicate name of actual target: <pstage/lib>libboost_system.a
error: previous virtual target { common%common.copy-libboost_system.a.STATIC_LIB { gcc%gcc.archive-libboost_system.a.STATIC_LIB { gcc%gcc.compile.c++-error_code.o.OBJ { error_code.cpp.CPP } } } }
error: created from ./stage-proper
error: another virtual target { common%common.copy-libboost_system.a.STATIC_LIB { gcc%gcc.archive-libboost_system.a.STATIC_LIB { gcc%gcc.compile.c++-error_code.o.OBJ { error_code.cpp.CPP } } } }
error: created from ./stage-proper
error: added properties: <threading>multi
error: removed properties: <threading>single
/usr/ports/pobj/boost-1.53.0/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build/virtual-target.jam:490: in actualize-no-scanner from module object(file-target)@4337
/usr/ports/pobj/boost-1.53.0/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build/virtual-target.jam:135: in object(file-target)@4337.actualize from module object(file-target)@4337
/usr/ports/pobj/boost-1.53.0/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:749: in load from module build-system
/usr/ports/pobj/boost-1.53.0/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/kernel/modules.jam:283: in import from module modules
/usr/ports/pobj/boost-1.53.0/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/kernel/bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build from module
/usr/ports/pobj/boost-1.53.0/boost_1_53_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module

*** Error 1 in . (Makefile:91 'do-build': @cd /usr/ports/pobj/boost-1.53.0/boost_1_53_0 &&  ./bjam -sNO_BZIP2=1  -d+2 -q  -j 1  cflags='-O2 ...)
*** Error 1 in . (/usr/ports/infrastructure/mk/bsd.port.mk:2619 '/usr/ports/pobj/boost-1.53.0/.build_done')
*** Error 1 in /usr/ports/devel/boost (/usr/ports/infrastructure/mk/bsd.port.mk:2342 'all')
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link has provided me with a hit of things I had to do. I often had too `#include<stdint.h>` and add `defined(__OpenBSD__)` in places

[svn ticket Ticket #8352:](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/8352/boost_filesystem.diff)